# How do I specify a list element name when serializing XML with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Consider the following JUnit test snippet which exercises serializing an object that contains multiple lists to XML.

```
static class MyItem {
    @JsonProperty("MyField")
    int myField;
}

static class MyLists {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "SomeItems")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyItem")
    List<MyItem> someItems;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "OtherItems")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyItem")
    List<MyItem> otherItems;
}

@Test
public void TestMultipleListSerialization() throws Exception {
    MyItem item1 = new MyItem();
    item1.myField = 42;

    MyItem item2 = new MyItem();
    item2.myField = 123;

    List<MyItem> someItems = Arrays.asList(item1, item2);

    MyItem item3 = new MyItem();
    item3.myField = 321;

    List<MyItem> otherItems = Collections.singletonList(item3);

    MyLists myLists = new MyLists();
    myLists.someItems = someItems;
    myLists.otherItems = otherItems;

    ObjectMapper serializer = new XmlMapper();
    String serialized = serializer.writeValueAsString(myLists);
}
```

When I run this test, I get the exception:  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple fields representing property "MyItem"`. However, if I use a different localName in one of the JacksonXmlProperty annotations, the name of the list element is wrong. For instance, if I changed one of the local names to "MyItemB", it would produce the following XML:

```
<MyLists>
    <SomeItems>
        <MyItem>
            <MyField>42</MyField>
        </MyItem>
        <MyItem>
            <MyField>123</MyField>
        </MyItem>
    </SomeItems>
    <OtherItems>
        <MyItemB>
            <MyField>321</MyField>
        </MyItemB>
    </OtherItems>
</MyLists>
```

What annotations should I be using instead to specify the list element name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Jackson since 2012. It will probably continue to be a problem for some time. When an object contains multiple lists with the same element name, the workaround is to put each list in a wrapper class that contains only that list.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/192